# Azure python version path is different than IDE python version

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug in vs code. I installed the new python version and removed the old ones. However, this is happening.

[image]

How can I fix this error?

Comment: press `ctrl + shift + p`, then type in `preferences user settings` then you can search ofr `python.pythonPath` and then give in full URL of your python 3.9 executable.

Comment: I altered the path, but the error still persists...

Comment: when you selected the python interpreter, did you select the globally installed version or  a virtual environment version(e.g. Conda )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used @BijayRegmi suggestion and it worked!